# Hadoop : Reading ORC files and putting into RDBMS?

Tags: hive, hadoop2, sqoop

I have a hive table which is stored in ORC files format. I want to export the data to a Teradata database. I researched sqoop but could not find a way to export ORC files.
Is there a way to make sqoop work for ORC ? or is there any other tool that I could use to export the data ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Hcatalog

`sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx:1433;databaseName=xxx;USERNAME=xxx;PASSWORD=xxx" --table rdmsTableName --hcatalog-database hiveDB --hcatalog-table hiveTableName`