# sqoop export of hive orc table

Tags: pyspark, sqoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table in orc format populated by pyspark dataframe_writer.
I need to export this table to oracle.I am having issues exporting the table because sqoop could not parse the orc file format.

Are there any special considerations or parameters that need to be specified with the sqoop command for exporting hive orc table.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google query points to that [blog post](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/how-to-export-a-hive-orc-table-to-a-oracle-database/) labeled quite explicitly...

> *How to Sqoop Export a Hive ORC table to a Oracle Database?*

And there is also that [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475364/hadoop-reading-orc-files-and-putting-into-rdbms) labeled...

> *Reading ORC files and putting into RDBMS?*

So it appears that you did not do any research.

By the way, did you consider using Spark to send the data *directly* into an Oracle staging table, via JDBC, without the intermediate ORC dump?

Comment: I did my research and saw the post to use hcatalog and tried it.I got a error which i need to reproduce to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on the same sqoop from orc to Oracle. Make sure you have your ORC table pre-created with correct datatypes as you have them in dataframe. Same order of the columns will also ease the sqoop. If you tried any command , please post it.